# Laravel "Call to a member function storeAs() on null" while using the enctype="multipart/form-data" tag on my blade form

Tags: php, laravel, forms, view, laravel-blade

I'm creating a basic upload form with different input fields, but once I submit my form I'm getting the error :

> Call to a member function storeAs() on null

I checked the problem it could have been and everyone was talking about adding the enctype="multipart/form-data" tag on the form... which is already present, so now I really have no clue about what my error could be...

drive.blade.php :

```
<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            {{ __('Drive') }}
        </h2>
    </x-slot>

    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg">
                <form action="/postForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <label for="file">File:</label><br>
                    <input type="file" id="file" name="file"><br>
                    <label for="folder_id">Folder ID :</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="folder_id" name="folder_id"><br>
                    <label for="organisation_id">Organisation ID :</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="organisation_id" name="organisation_id"><br>
                    <label for="organisation_type">Organisation type :</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="organisation_type" name="organisation_type"><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
```

My route :  `Route::get('postForm', "App\Http\Controllers\FileController@store");`

My controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $userLogged = Auth::user();

        $document = $request->file("file");
//        dd($document);


        $organisation_type = $request->organisation_type;
        $organisation_id   = $request->organisation_id;
        $folder_id         = $request->folder_id;


        $path = $document->storeAs('public', "tempName");

        return response()->json(["result" => "ok"], 201);
    }
```

Comment: Change the route to be a POST route `Route::post('postForm',  ...)` and then add `method="POST"` to your form. Files can't be uploaded using GET requests.

Comment: By doing that I now have an Error 419 but yes, I don't have the storeAs on null

Comment: I added "@csrf" in the form and now everything works fien! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error Is Showing To me 419 Page Expired Because You Don't Add

`@csrf` In Your Blade

Or You Can Add `<input value='csrf_token()' hidden>`